# Adding Numpy arrays like Counters

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, counter

Since collections.Counter is so slow, I am pursuing a faster method of summing mapped values in Python 2.7. It seems like a simple concept and I'm kind of disappointed in the built-in Counter method.

Basically, I need to be able to take arrays like this:

```
array([[ 0.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  1.]])

array([[ 0.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  5.]])
```

And then "add" them so they look like this:

```
array([[ 0.,  5.],
       [ 1.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  7.],
       [ 3.,  1.]])
```

If there isn't a good way to do this quickly and efficiently, I'm open to any other ideas that will allow me to do something similar to this, and I'm open to modules other than Numpy.

Thanks!

Edit: Ready for some speedtests?
Intel win 64bit machine. All of the following values are in seconds; 20000 loops.

> collections.Counter results: 
>   2.131000, 2.125000, 2.125000
>
> Divakar's union1d + masking results: 
>   1.641000, 1.633000, 1.625000
>
> Divakar's union1d + indexing results: 
>   0.625000, 0.625000, 0.641000
>
> Histogram results: 
>   1.844000, 1.938000, 1.858000
>
> Pandas results: 
>   16.659000, 16.686000, 16.885000

Conclusions: union1d + indexing wins, the array size is too small for Pandas to be effective, and the histogram approach blew my mind with its simplicity but I'm guessing it takes too much overhead to create. All of the responses I received were very good, though. [This is what I used to get the numbers.](https://gist.github.com/UberPyro/7593df04d0403b53d30e60487daaf8d0) Thanks again!

Edit: And it should be mentioned that using `Counter1.update(Counter2.elements())` is terrible despite doing the same exact thing (65.671000 sec).

Later Edit: I've been thinking about this a lot, and I've came to realize that, with Numpy, it might be more effective to **fill each array with zeros** so that the first column isn't even needed since we can just use the index, and that would also make it much easier to add multiple arrays together as well as do other functions. Additionally, Pandas makes more sense than Numpy since there would be no need to 0-fill, and it would definitely be more effective with large data sets (however, Numpy has the advantage of being compatible on more platforms, like GAE, if that matters at all). Lastly, the answer I checked was definitely the best answer for the exact question I asked--adding the two arrays in the way I showed--but I think what I needed was a change in perspective.

Comment: Why does the result have 4 rows?

Comment: Because the rows of the resultant equals the number of unique first indexes in the union of the all first indexes of the arrays. Since in the top arrays, only the top one has a "2" and only the middle one has a "3", the bottom one has both a two and a three.

Comment: Do you know what the maximum value in the first column is?

Comment: Yes, its presumed that I know the number range. For what I'm doing, the numbers are going to be a sort of ID.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what exactly are you doing with `collections.Counter`?

Comment: Sorry, it's kind of really difficult to explain. I'll use a strange analogy. Let's just say that each number on the left is a "monster" of some sort, and each number on the right is a rating of how well that monster is defended against. Using counters, you can add the ratings together. Edit: And I'm doing this like 20000 times for optimization purposes.

Comment: Could you add the range of values your first "column" and how many rows do these arrays have? Just some order of magnitude would be enough.

Comment: The first column can contain up to 170 values. The performance issues comes from repeating the function so many times.

Comment: Could there be repeats/duplicates in each first column of the two input arrays?

Comment: Each individual array cannot have a duplicate in the first column, but as shown in my example the top and the middle arrays have overlap. But no duplicates in any 1 array, so the answer is no.

Comment: Could there be gaps, like the first column of first array be : `[0,2,4]` and first col of second array be `[0,2,3]`. So, there's no `1`. Could that happen?

Comment: Yes, there can be gaps.

Comment: Speed tests are in!

Comment: With such low numbers it certainly doesn't make sense to use pandas (just as your speed test points out). However, do you have the full input (of all 2000 iterations) available up-front? 
If so it is worth doing a vectorized version of  the entire run, not just 120-odd values at the time.

Comment: In a way, yes. Basically, the 20000 iterations come from combinatorics (created from itertools.combinations). There are up to 6 elements (the sample) chosen from a pool, and the pool adjusts its size so that the number of iterations don't pass ~20000. These 6 elements are then converted into an array (or Counter/Dictionary) through the use of a dictionary (mapped directly). Each group of up to 6 arrays are then "added" like I showed in the OP. Edit: @ilmarinen yeah I should look into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach with `np.union1d` and `masking` -

```
def app1(a,b):
    c0 = np.union1d(a[:,0],b[:,0])

    out = np.zeros((len(c0),2))
    out[:,0] = c0

    mask1 = np.in1d(c0,a[:,0])
    out[mask1,1] = a[:,1]

    mask2 = np.in1d(c0,b[:,0])
    out[mask2,1] += b[:,1]
    return out
```

Sample run -

```
In [174]: a
Out[174]: 
array([[  0.,   2.],
       [ 12.,   2.],
       [ 23.,   1.]])

In [175]: b
Out[175]: 
array([[  0.,   3.],
       [  1.,   1.],
       [ 12.,   5.]])

In [176]: app1(a,b)
Out[176]: 
array([[  0.,   5.],
       [  1.,   1.],
       [ 12.,   7.],
       [ 23.,   1.]])
```

Here's another with `np.union1d` and `indexing` -

```
def app2(a,b):
    n = np.maximum(a[:,0].max(), b[:,0].max())+1
    c0 = np.union1d(a[:,0],b[:,0])
    out0 = np.zeros((int(n), 2))
    out0[a[:,0].astype(int),1] = a[:,1]

    out0[b[:,0].astype(int),1] += b[:,1]

    out = out0[c0.astype(int)]
    out[:,0] = c0
    return out
```

For the case where all indices are covered by the first column values in `a` and `b` -

```
def app2_specific(a,b):
    c0 = np.union1d(a[:,0],b[:,0])
    n = c0[-1]+1
    out0 = np.zeros((int(n), 2))
    out0[a[:,0].astype(int),1] = a[:,1]        
    out0[b[:,0].astype(int),1] += b[:,1]
    out0[:,0] = c0
    return out0
```

Sample run -

```
In [234]: a
Out[234]: 
array([[ 0.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  1.]])

In [235]: b
Out[235]: 
array([[ 0.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  5.]])

In [236]: app2_specific(a,b)
Out[236]: 
array([[ 0.,  5.],
       [ 1.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  7.],
       [ 3.,  1.]])
```

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Would love to do that too, if and when OP posts that version.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the number of fields, use `np.bincount`.

```
c = np.vstack([a, b])
counts = np.bincount(c[:, 0], weights = c[:, 1], minlength = numFields)
out = np.vstack([np.arange(numFields), counts]).T
```

This works if you're getting all your data at once.  Make a list of your arrays and `vstack` them.  If you're getting data chunks sequentially, you can use `np.add.at` to do the same thing.

```
out = np.zeros(2, numFields)
out[:, 0] = np.arange(numFields)
np.add.at(out[:, 1], a[:, 0], a[:, 1])
np.add.at(out[:, 1], b[:, 0], b[:, 1])
```

Comment: My last one was dangerously close to your second one. Think I will rollback to previous version of it. That `range` was great idea!

Comment: Think you need to modify your solutions as OP says he/she [might have gaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45021120/adding-numpy-arrays-like-counters#comment77018565_45021120) and they are looking to get an ["union" version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45021120/adding-numpy-arrays-like-counters#comment77016647_45021120) in the output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a basic histogram, [this will deal with gaps, too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45021120/adding-numpy-arrays-like-counters#comment77018787_45021401). You can filter out zero-count entries if need be.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[ 0.,  2.],
              [ 2.,  2.],
              [ 3.,  1.]])

y = np.array([[ 0.,  3.],
              [ 1.,  1.],
              [ 2.,  5.],
              [ 5.,  3.]])

c, w = np.vstack((x,y)).T
h, b = np.histogram(c, weights=w, 
                    bins=np.arange(c.min(),c.max()+2))
r = np.vstack((b[:-1], h)).T
print(r)
# [[ 0.  5.]
#  [ 1.  1.]
#  [ 2.  7.]
#  [ 3.  1.]
#  [ 4.  0.]
#  [ 5.  3.]]
r_nonzero = r[r[:,1]!=0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas have some functions doing exactly what you intend

```
import pandas as pd
pda = pd.DataFrame(a).set_index(0)
pdb = pd.DataFrame(b).set_index(0)
result = pd.concat([pda, pdb], axis=1).fillna(0).sum(axis=1)
```

Edit: If you actually need the data back in numpy format, just do

```
array_res = result.reset_index(name=1).values
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a quintessential grouping problem, which [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) (disclaimer: I am its author) was created to solve elegantly and efficiently:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
C = np.concatenate([A, B], axis=0)
labels, sums = npi.group_by(C[:, 0]).sum(C[:, 1])
```

Note: its cleaner to maintain your label arrays as a seperate int array; floats are finicky when it comes to labeling things, with positive and negative zeros, and printed values not relaying all binary state. Better to use ints for that.

Comment: is your numpy_indexed compatible with pyinstaller? Edit: and is it implemented in Python or are there C extensions?

Comment: No c extensions, so in principle you can just copy the source to your project and run it; though I strongly recommend conda for python package management

Comment: I'm not sure where else to ask so: I get an error when I try to download numpy_indexed using pip, and when trying to download Conda using pip. With numpy_indexed, my error is: "Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1" and the end of the path it gives is "appdata\local\temp\pip-build-u6xyi9\numpy-indexed\". When trying to download Conda, I get "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement menuinst (from conda) (from versions: )" and under that "No matching distribution found for menuinst (from conda)". Please help? I'd like to test its speed.

Comment: with pip, try in installing pyyaml first before numpy_indexed. That conda error I am not familiar with. Have you tried downloading miniconda3 from their website? https://conda.io/miniconda.html